# How to check used VideoCard's resources, if good or bad?

Tags: video, health

There is HDD-Health programs, that can measure if HDD is in good or bad condition and other details.

Is something like that available, to check VideoCard ? I ask this because want to check if specific used VideoCard is in good or bad condition.

Comment: What OS and price margin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I only now the MemtestCL. We used this in an application once. But it works on the command line, too.

Memtest description on github:

> MemtestCL is a program to test the memory and logic of OpenCL-enabled GPUs, CPUs, and accelerators for errors.

https://github.com/ihaque/memtestCL

Maybe there are tools that use MemtestCl and run on your OS to make it easier to use.